# Finding the original index after stripping a string

Tags: java

I have a function like the following:

```
int getIndex(String noisyString) {
    String quietString = noisyString.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");

    int quietStringIndex = findIndexInQuietString(quietString);

    return originalIndexInNoisyString; // ???
}
```

After stripping a string of all non alphabetical characters, I find an arbitrarily chosen index inside the stripped string. How can I convert this index back to one that can be used for the unstripped string?

Comment: You need a data structure to map original to created positions. There are a few possible approaches with different trade offs. What did you try first, before asking this question?

Comment: I spent a while thinking about whether I would have to create a new implementation of `String#replaceAll`, as otherwise I see no way to create a map of original to created positions. I was wondering if there exists a more elegant solution, or something that is commonly used.

Comment: If your arbitrarily chosen index is, say, 42, then just step through the original string until you find the 42nd char that is an alphabetical character.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking. Do you want to find the character at the same index of the randomly chosen index, or do you want to find the index of the same exact character in the noisy string?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to get the index in the non-filtered string of the same character at the chosen index in the filtered string.

(ie. you have a String s1 = "abc123def" s1.replaceAll() = "abcdef". You want to get the original index of the character at index 4 in the filtered String.
The character at index 4 in the filtered String is e. Its index value in the unfiltered String is 7.)

The simplest brute force way to do this would be to use a counter to go through the string keeping track of what index you are up to, meanwhile having a separate counter variable to keep track of how many characters that have been passed that are valid for the filtered string.

```
public static int getOriginalIndex(String s, int index){

    if (index > s.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").length()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("index is invalid");
    }

    int counter;
    int validCharCounter = 0;

    for (counter = 0; counter < s.length() && validCharCounter < index; counter++) {

        if (s.charAt(counter) >= 'a' && s.charAt(counter) <= 'z')
            validCharCounter++;

   }

    return counter;
}
```